# chart.js 3 - "title" not available in options

Tags: typescript, chart.js

I want to dynamically change title.color for a scale, however "title" isn't available in options after the chart is created.

The scale is defined like this:

```
scales: {
          yTemp: {
            type: "linear",
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'Text',
              color: '#f00'
            },
            grid: {
              borderColor: '#f00'
            },
            ticks: {
              color: '#f00'
            },
          },
```

I'm able to change grid and ticks colour like this:

```
myChart.options.scales['yTemp'].ticks.color = '#333';
myChart.options.scales['yTemp'].grid.borderColor = '#333';
```

however, for some reason I can't do the same to change the title color like this:

```
myChart.options.scales['yTemp'].title.color = '#333';
```

[image]

The error message is as follows:

TS2339: Property 'title' does not exist on type '_DeepPartialObject<{ type: "linear"; } & CartesianScaleOptions & { beginAtZero: boolean; suggestedMin?: number; suggestedMax?: number; grace?: string | number; ticks: { format: NumberFormatOptions; precision: number; stepSize: number; count: number; }; }> | ... 4 more ... | _DeepPartialObject<...>'.
Property 'title' does not exist on type '_DeepPartialObject<{ type: "radialLinear"; } & CoreScaleOptions & { animate: boolean; angleLines: { display: boolean; color: Scriptable<Color, ScriptableScaleContext>; lineWidth: Scriptable<...>; borderDash: Scriptable<...>; borderDashOffset: Scriptable<...>; }; ... 7 more ...; ticks: TickOptions & { ...; }; }>'.

... any ideas? I'm using TypeScript - are the TypeScript definitions not complete?

Comment: Provide the error message as code, not as an image. `.colour` is not the correct spelling. After you successfully update the option, you'll need to call `myChart.update();`. See [Updating Charts](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html). This comment isn't an answer, it's to help you clean up your question so that you can get an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... I changed .colour to .color (typo) however the issue is with the .title (even .title.color throws this error) ... I've now put in the complete error message from TypeScript.  I am doing a myChart.update() which works correctly for ticks and grid changes, but it won't compile because it can't find .title

Answer (score 0):

I had to cast scales to CartesianScaleOptions like so:

```
(<CartesianScaleOptions>this.chartMainObj.options.scales[scaleName]).title.color = colour;
```